# Azure app service startup command (required)

Tags: linux, azure, asp.net-core, continuous-deployment, azureportal

I am deploying my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app to **Azure App Service**. While creating the new app service, I chose **Linux as Operating System**. In deployment center, when I deploy the app, it prompts me to enter a **startup command**. Everywhere I read about it it says **startup command is optional**. But when I deploy, it doesn't get further without this.

I have recently deployed other app services on **windows** and this was not the problem then. The startup command I am entering is **dotnet <project.dll>**. It deploys successfully. But after the deployment whenever I hit an API endpoint, it gives **500 Internal Server Error**.

My question is:
What is the purpose of startup command? Why is this returns with 500 when deployed to linux.

S

Comment: Which way do you use to deploy your application to Azure Web Service? Can you share the link?

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I diagnosed the problem. My deployed app service is not whitelisted to access database. That is the reason for 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 6):

It seems your startup command is correct refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#built-in-images).

You could check if this setting had been set already in Configuration, and check if the .dll file name is correct. As far as I known, this setting is necessary under Linux environment.
[image]

For 500 Internal Server Error, it's a error from server side, sometimes it means your web app is not prepared, and restart it would solve the problem.

If not solved, check the wwwroot file structure in kudu. ->.scm.azurewebsites.net If the file structure not correct, try another way to deploy.

---

### Update

As your own reply, you [connected your app to database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-windows). If issue still here, try add **sql server** policy like this:
[image]