# How to customize the startup command for Azure app service?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am using Azure app service to deploy a `.NET 6.0` website, running in a Windows-based environment. It seems like they use `MSBuild` as a default startup command. I am just wondering how to customize the startup command via the Azure web console or any config file. Since I couldn't find the "Startup command" field under "Configurations" > "General Settings", the field mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476513/azure-app-service-startup-command-required) is missing.
[image]

Comment: this command is for linux Web Apps only, probably

Comment: Yes,you need to deploy the app to Azure Linux app

Comment: @Harshitha, I am still a newbie in the Azure world and don't understand how a .Net project runs in a Linux app?

Comment: Instead of deploying the app to Windows, you need to deploy your app to Azure Linux app service, If you wan ta Startup command option.

Comment: For windows app you don't need a start up command.By the way why do you want the startup command?

Comment: I would like to customize the startup command to `dotnet build & dotnet publish`.

Comment: Try to set it in `web.config` file and check once.You can see the file in `site\wwwroot` deployed folder.

Comment: Is your app not running with it ?

Comment: No, basically there is no `web.config` in the project, I think I have to discuss it with our developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256983/discussion-between-harshitha-and-corey).

Comment: You can set the PRE_BUILD_COMMAND and POST_BUILD_COMMAND environment variables in app settings.

Comment: @alex will `PRE_BUILD_COMMAND` overwrite the default `MSBuild` command at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find the "Startup command" field under "Configurations" > "General Settings"

The option to add the Startup command in General Settings is available only for the Azure App Services deployed in Linux Environment.

[image]

- You can see the MSDoc's [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#built-in-images) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-with-pm2) explains the way to add a startup for only Linux Apps.

> customize the startup command to `dotnet build & dotnet publish`

- As I have mentioned in the comments, the app deployed in Windows App service contains the `web.config` file with default settings (`processPath=dotnet`).

```cs
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Startup28Feb.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

- Even the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-windows#run-with-pm2:%7E:text=The%20generated%20web.config%20is%20tailored%20to%20the%20detected%20start%20script.), says the same.

> The generated *web.config* is tailored to the detected start script

- Make sure the app is deployed properly and contains all the files in the KUDU Console.

[image]

AFAIK,the .NET Core App deployed in Windows Environment does not require any startup command to set manually to run the Application.

Comment: What is the difference (at runtime) between deploying dotnet websites in Windows environment and Linux environment? If I don't use docker.

Comment: Refer this [Link](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet-blog/windows-linux-compare-asp-net-core-install-hosting) more details.